# Dropdown menu items not stacking vertically

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Hi I have a website with a dropdown menu and for some reason its items stack horizontally.
The HTML is like this

```
<li id="menuitem">a</li>
<ul id="dropdown">
<li id="dropdownelement">b</li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS sets the ul to hidden unless hover. And li elements to relative

https://jsfiddle.net/u8pmtc4z/

Comment: Well, they are floating left, what did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your implementation.

You can test this [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/xpzd3196/1) and see if this is the desired behaviour.

You should set the `ul ul` elements to be positioned `absolute`, and your `ul li` to `relative` with an `inline-block` display prop.

Then, change your `#navbar ul li:hover ul` to be like this:

```
#navbar ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This sets the nested dropdown to be positioned below the parent as well as aligned to the left.

Also, you have used the `#accountDropDownElement` id twice in your markup. I replaced it as a class in my demo because `id`s must be unique!

Here's the full code:

```css
#navbar ul {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-table;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 965px;
}

#navbar ul:after {
 content: "";
 clear: both; 
 display: block;
}

#navbar ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 66px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar ul ul li {
  float: none; 
  position: relative;
}


#navbar ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#navbar ul li:hover > a {
  border: 1px rgb(204, 255, 102) solid;
 background-color: rgb(204, 255, 102);
 box-shadow: none;
}

#navbar ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar ul li:hover ul li {
  float: none;
}

#navbar ul li a {
 border-radius: 25px;
 border: 1px rgb(57, 232, 38) solid;
 background-color: rgb(57, 232, 38);
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 color: white;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 font-family: "micross";
 font-size: 30px;
 padding: 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover {
 border: 1px rgb(204, 255, 102) solid;
 background-color: rgb(204, 255, 102);
 box-shadow: none;
}
#accountButton:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

#accountDropDownImage {
    float: left;
}

.accountDropDownElement {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(57, 232, 38);
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 20px; 
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/navbar.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
  <ul id="navbarList">
    <li id="homeButton"><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
    <li id="blogButton"><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
    <li id="downloadsButton"><a href="downloads.php">Downloads</a></li>
    <li id="managerButton"><a href="manager.php">Manager</a></li>
    <li id="accountButton"><a id='accountAButton'    href='manager.php'>Luke</a>
      <ul id='dropDownList'>
        <li><p class='accountDropDownElement'>Logout</p></li>
        <li><p class='accountDropDownElement'>Login</p></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you adjust the width in your css to be 65 instead of 965 you will see the links stack on the left as Im assuming your wanting.